# Windows Update KB4056892 for CPU Vulnerbility

Tags: security, windows-update

Regarding the recent CPU security bug, Microsoft released a patch to fix.

However, when google it. I can only see updates/patch for windows 10 OS. Where to download for the windows server? e.g.2008, 2012?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

This security patch is shipped as updates with individual KB numbers for each OS codebase (including the different Windows 10 feature updates).

KB4056892 is specifically for Windows 10 Version 1709

KB4056890 is for Windows 10 Version 1607, Windows Server 2016, Windows 10 Mobile

KB4056895 is for Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

etc.

The advisory [ADV180002](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/ADV180002) has a big table of KB links for all the OS versions.